# How to avoid zombie code rising from the dead in git rebase?

Tags: git

This has happened to me more than once.

Working on a branch. Someone else removes a chunk of code and pushes to master. The removed code is distinct from anything I'm working on, but it's present in my branch.

I rebase on master. Suddenly, the removed code reappears in my branch, looking like I added it.

Is there any advanced git-config flags to set that would "honor" master removing code? Or is it always going to look like the code was added in my branch?

Comment: When does this happens 'Suddenly', (I at least need more info) just after the rebase or after you commit something ?

Comment: If your branch never touched the deleted code, I don't see how this could happen.

Comment: What is the exact commands sequence you run when you *"rebase on master"*?

Comment: Eyorther - just after I rebase.

Comment: axiac - "git pull" where my .gitconfig contains "[pull] rebase=true".

Comment: The one obvious (well, "obvious-ish" perhaps) possibility is if someone did a *force*-push to *remove* some commits, in which case your `git pull` second step may think that the commits they removed, should be put back from your copies of them. Otherwise I'd need to see a lot more background and setup before I could guess.

Comment: Only thing I can think of that might cause this is if you've got your conflict resolution on rebase set to use your changes by default in your .gitattributes files.